# python glob & sys.argv error, and regex not working

Tags: python, regex, glob, argv

I'm having two problems with a script that uses glob, sys, re, and os modules.  The script enumerates a directory and searches all files for a string.  It runs if I assign the absolute path to a variable, but doesn't perform the regex.  I need to change the script to use sys.argv so the user can specify a path in the terminal (example: `./replace_students.py /home/alex/Documents/`).  When I changed the dirname variable from `"dirname = "/home/alex/Documents/""` to `"dirname = sys.argv[1:]"` I get the error

> "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found".

I need assistance with the error and getting the regex to work.

```
import os, glob, sys, re

#dirname = "/home/alex/Documents"
dirname = sys.argv[1:]
os.listdir(dirname)

for filename in glob.glob('*'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()

    if 'students' in contents:
        contents = contents.replace(r" students", "pupils")
    print contents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[1:]` means you want all the items from the second until the last, in effect instead of getting one string, you get a list (yes, its a list even if it contains one item).
 `os.listdir` needs a single path, not a list

instead do:

```
dirname = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: You're explanation was understandable & helpful.  I made the changes and it worked.  Thanks!